# missing modules after installing kernel

Tags: kernel

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. Suspend stopped working some time ago. I suspect it's the latest upgrade to kernel 6.2
The upgrade uninstalled previous versions of the kernel (5.19). So I reinstalled one version with

`sudo apt install linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic`

When I reboot and select this kernel, I get an error

```
Gave up waiting root file system device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
 - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; is /dev)
ALERT! UUID=1a7e95c4-8050-4fb9-8a0b-84b63a8c32ae does not exist. Dropping to a shell|!
```

I don't know why this is failing and how to repair this.

Comment: Didn't you also install linux-modules-extra and linux-headers? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: `grub` has been configured to boot from a particular disk/partition, the one with `UUID=1a7e95c4-8050-4fb9-8a0b-84b63a8c32ae`, and, it "`does not exist.`".

Comment: That was that, linux-modules-extra wasn't installed. Thanks @chili555